# Gitlab CI: Cannot connect to Docker Daemon

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using the following
 - Windows 7
 - Docker Toolbox
 - Gitlab CE 11.0.1

I am running the following in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
stages:
 - build

job 1:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - tower

  script:
    - docker-machine ls
    - docker run hello-world
```

The `config.toml` for `Gitlab-Runner` is kept simple

```
[[runners]]
  name = "vue-django"
  url = "https://xxx/"
  token = "xxx"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "cmd"
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

The commands are working perfectly in Windows command prompt once I login into the machine and make sure I have run `Docker Quickstart Terminal` atleast once to start the Virtual machine hosting Docker.

Unfortunately, when I run the same using the Gitlab-Runner using `Shell Executor`, I am getting the following error-

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.8.0 (4745a6f3)
  on vue-django f72dfbdb
Using Shell executor...
Running on xxx...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at 30a70e4 Update .gitlab-ci.yml
From https://xxx/vue-django
   30a70e4..88857ef  master     -> origin/master
Checking out 88857ef3 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           Unknown   Unable to query docker version: Get https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.15/version: x509: certificate is valid for 192.168.99.101, not 192.168.99.100
$ docker run hello-world
docker: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.37/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
See 'docker run --help'.
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 127
```

I have searched a lot and the solutions posted work, but not for Gitlab-Runner. I never have an issue running the commands on the Windows 7 machine or my Windows 10 machine, just unable to run them via Gitlab-Runner on Windows 7.

Any help or alternative options as it is quite frustrating? Also, why are commands running with `'$'` as in bash even when mentioned `cmd` as the executor?